# Need to create multiple new variables simultaneously using across() in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset where I need to adjust multiple variables for inflation. It looks something like this.

| year | price1 | price2 | price3 | price4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | 1.149 | 1.149 | 1.163 | 1.172 |
| 2004 | 1.169 | 1.164 | 1.184 | 1.18 |
| 2005 | 1.167 | 1.166 | 1.183 | 1.178 |

I need to put these all in a constant format (like 2020 dollars). I can do this pretty easily with the `adjust_for_inflation` function from the `priceR` package. However, there are a **lot** of price variables, so I'd like to create them all automatically. I've been trying to do with `across` but it isn't working. Here's what I've been trying.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(priceR)

#this is it done manually, which would take hours

df %>%  mutate(adjusted_price1=adjust_for_inflation(price1,year,"US",to_date = 2020))

#here's my attempt to do it all at once
price.vars <- df %>% select(-year) %>% names()

dollars2020 <- function(x){
  
  y <- adjust_for_inflation(x,year,"US",to_date = 2020)
}

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(price.vars, dollars2020,.names ="adjusted_{col}"))
```

As far as I can tell, this should be spitting out a list of new variables with names like `adjusted_price1` and so forth. But it's not working. I'd really appreciate any help anyone could give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you. Instead of a custom function, I passed `adjust_for_inflation` directly into your `dplyr` line:

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(priceR)

price.vars <- df  %>% select(-year) %>% names()

df %>% mutate(across(price.vars, ~ adjust_for_inflation(.x, year, "US", to_date = 2020), .names = "adjusted_{col}"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
   year price1 price2 price3 price4 adjusted_price1 adjusted_price2 adjusted_price3 adjusted_price4
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1  2003   1.15   1.15   1.16   1.17            1.62            1.62            1.64            1.65
2  2004   1.17   1.16   1.18   1.18            1.60            1.59            1.62            1.62
3  2005   1.17   1.17   1.18   1.18            1.55            1.55            1.57            1.56
```

**Data**

```
df <- tibble(fread("year    price1  price2  price3  price4
2003    1.149   1.149   1.163   1.172
2004    1.169   1.164   1.184   1.18
2005    1.167   1.166   1.183   1.178"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with your use of `across`, it's your function. Firstly, you are passing a variable called `year` to `adjust_for_inflation` that does not exist. Secondly, your function doesn't return anything. If you change it to:

```r
dollars2020 <- function(x){
  
  adjust_for_inflation(x, 2022,"US",to_date = 2020)
}
```

You'll get:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(price.vars, dollars2020,.names ="adjusted_{col}"))
#>   year price1 price2 price3 price4 adjusted_price1 adjusted_price2 adjusted_price3 adjusted_price4
#> 1 2003  1.149  1.149  1.163  1.172        1.134999        1.134999        1.148828        1.157719
#> 2 2004  1.169  1.164  1.184  1.180        1.154755        1.149816        1.169572        1.165621
#> 3 2005  1.167  1.166  1.183  1.178        1.152779        1.151792        1.168585        1.163645
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I need the 'year' input to be be the year entry for each observation, not fixed like this. I can't have it be fixed to a specific year. Do you know how I could make it dynamic in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Is it just the naming part that doesn't work? if so then change {col} to {.col}