# Calculate cumulative mean row-wise on groups of columns with a common names pattern

Tags: r, dplyr

### Context

I want calculate cumulative mean row-wise, on different sets of columns defined by pattern in the column names.

Example data, with two sets of columns starting with `a` and `b`, respectively:

```
a1 = c(1, 2, 3)
a2 = c(4, 5, 6)
a3 = c(7, 8, 9)
a4 = c(10, 11, 12)
b1 = c(10, 20, 30)
b2 = c(40, 50, 60)
b3 = c(70, 80, 90)
b4 = c(100, 110, 120)

df = data.frame(a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4)

> df
  a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4
1  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100
2  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110
3  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120
```

The first set of calculations is performed among the columns where the names start with an `a`:

`a1_2` is the mean value of `a1` and `a2`.

`a1_3` is the mean value of `a1`, `a2` and `a3`.

`a1_4` is the mean value of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and `a4`.

Similarly, I want to perform the same calculations on the "`b` columns": `b1_2`, `b1_3` and `b1_4` are calculated in exactly the same way as `a1_2`, `a1_3` and `a1_4`.

I can generate `a1_2` to `b1_4` with the following code. But in the real case I have too many similar variables to generate.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(a1_2 = mean(c(a1, a2)),
         a1_3 = mean(c(a1, a2, a3)),
         a1_4 = mean(c(a1, a2, a3, a4)),
         b1_2 = mean(c(b1, b2)),
         b1_3 = mean(c(b1, b2, b3)),
         b1_4 = mean(c(b1, b2, b3, b4))) %>% 
  ungroup()

  a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4 a1_2 a1_3 a1_4 b1_2 b1_3 b1_4
1  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100  2.5    4  5.5   25   40   55
2  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110  3.5    5  6.5   35   50   65
3  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120  4.5    6  7.5   45   60   75
```

### Question

How can I perform these calculations more efficiently, without having to generate them one by one manually? These generated variables have a pattern, and the pattern is to calculate the average of multiple variables.

### What I've done

I checked a question related to mine ([Need to create multiple new variables simultaneously using across() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811971/need-to-create-multiple-new-variables-simultaneously-using-across-in-r)). But in this question, the new variables generated by the author are not related to the other variables in the data frame, which is not the same as the problem I encountered.

Comment: I wish the question had more context.

Comment: Hi @IRTFM, I've updated the context to describe the problem I'm having in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` option in one pipe (thanks to @jav for nice approach):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  mutate(group = sub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*", "\\1", name),
         number = gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", name)) %>%
  group_by(id, group) %>%
  mutate(avg_value = cummean(value),
         col_name := paste0(group, min(number), "_", number)) %>%
  filter(number != 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = col_name, values_from = avg_value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  merge(df %>% mutate(id = row_number()), ., by = 'id') %>%
  select(-id)
#>   a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4 a1_2 a1_3 a1_4 b1_2 b1_3 b1_4
#> 1  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100  2.5    4  5.5   25   40   55
#> 2  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110  3.5    5  6.5   35   50   65
#> 3  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120  4.5    6  7.5   45   60   75
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to solve this specifically using `mutate` but I can show you an approach using `data.table`.

First, I'll explain my way of approaching this:

1. To start, for columns that start with `a`, you're looking for mean of `(a1, a2)`, mean of `(a1, a2, a3)`, etc. I'll simplify to just call these mean of `(1, 2)`, mean of `(1, 2, 3)`, etc. From the looks of it, we can re-phrase this as you needing a `cumulative mean` across groupings of columns.
2. We can try to use `cummean` by group but that'll only work for rows.
3. So we just re-shape our dataset to long format, do a `cummean` and then re-shape it to its original `wide` format.

Import packages:

```
   library(data.table)
   library(dplyr)
```

Convert your data frame to `data.table` format:

```
   setDT(df)
```

Add a row number to the data frame:

```
   df[, row_id := .I]
```

Re-shape to long format:

```
   df2 = melt.data.table(df, id.vars = "row_id")
```

At this point, your data looks as follows:

```
    row_id variable value
 1:      1       a1     1
 2:      2       a1     2
 3:      3       a1     3
 4:      1       a2     4
 5:      2       a2     5
 6:      3       a2     6
 7:      1       a3     7
 8:      2       a3     8
 9:      3       a3     9
10:      1       a4    10
11:      2       a4    11
12:      3       a4    12
13:      1       b1    10
14:      2       b1    20
15:      3       b1    30
16:      1       b2    40
17:      2       b2    50
18:      3       b2    60
19:      1       b3    70
20:      2       b3    80
21:      3       b3    90
22:      1       b4   100
23:      2       b4   110
24:      3       b4   120
```

Let's split out the letter from the number so that we can create groups by the letter:

```
   df2[, group := substr(variable, 1, 1)]
   df2[, number := as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", variable))]
```

At this point, we have:

```
    row_id variable value group number
 1:      1       a1     1     a      1
 2:      2       a1     2     a      1
 3:      3       a1     3     a      1
 4:      1       a2     4     a      2
 5:      2       a2     5     a      2
 6:      3       a2     6     a      2
 7:      1       a3     7     a      3
 8:      2       a3     8     a      3
 9:      3       a3     9     a      3
10:      1       a4    10     a      4
11:      2       a4    11     a      4
12:      3       a4    12     a      4
13:      1       b1    10     b      1
14:      2       b1    20     b      1
15:      3       b1    30     b      1
16:      1       b2    40     b      2
17:      2       b2    50     b      2
18:      3       b2    60     b      2
19:      1       b3    70     b      3
20:      2       b3    80     b      3
21:      3       b3    90     b      3
22:      1       b4   100     b      4
23:      2       b4   110     b      4
24:      3       b4   120     b      4
```

Now, we can take the cumulative mean of `value` by `row_id` and `group`:

```
   df2[, avg_val :=cummean(value), by=c("row_id", "group")]
```

We then create your column naming convention as follows:

```
   df2[, col_name := paste0(group, min(number), "_", number)]
```

As this point, we have:

```
    row_id variable value group number avg_val col_name
 1:      1       a1     1     a      1     1.0     a1_1
 2:      2       a1     2     a      1     2.0     a1_1
 3:      3       a1     3     a      1     3.0     a1_1
 4:      1       a2     4     a      2     2.5     a1_2
 5:      2       a2     5     a      2     3.5     a1_2
 6:      3       a2     6     a      2     4.5     a1_2
 7:      1       a3     7     a      3     4.0     a1_3
 8:      2       a3     8     a      3     5.0     a1_3
 9:      3       a3     9     a      3     6.0     a1_3
10:      1       a4    10     a      4     5.5     a1_4
11:      2       a4    11     a      4     6.5     a1_4
12:      3       a4    12     a      4     7.5     a1_4
13:      1       b1    10     b      1    10.0     b1_1
14:      2       b1    20     b      1    20.0     b1_1
15:      3       b1    30     b      1    30.0     b1_1
16:      1       b2    40     b      2    25.0     b1_2
17:      2       b2    50     b      2    35.0     b1_2
18:      3       b2    60     b      2    45.0     b1_2
19:      1       b3    70     b      3    40.0     b1_3
20:      2       b3    80     b      3    50.0     b1_3
21:      3       b3    90     b      3    60.0     b1_3
22:      1       b4   100     b      4    55.0     b1_4
23:      2       b4   110     b      4    65.0     b1_4
24:      3       b4   120     b      4    75.0     b1_4
```

We can get rid of the rows where `number = 1` as these represent the original data. From there, we can cast it to wide format, and merge back the original data:

```
   df2 = df2[number != 1]
   result = dcast.data.table(df2, row_id ~ col_name, value.var = "avg_val")

   result = merge(df, result, by = "row_id")

   result[, row_id := NULL]
```

The final result is:

```
   a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4 a1_2 a1_3 a1_4 b1_2 b1_3 b1_4
1:  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100  2.5    4  5.5   25   40   55
2:  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110  3.5    5  6.5   35   50   65
3:  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120  4.5    6  7.5   45   60   75
```

Comment: When melting, you may use `measure` to specify `measure.vars` with a regex: `melt(df, measure.vars = measure(group, number, pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)"))`. Then you can skip the `substr` and `gsub` steps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach in base R that:

1. defines a small wrapper function applying `rowMeans` to the sets of columns starting with variable `v`.
2. column binds the original data.frame with the output of the wrapper based on the names `"a"` and `"b"` (this can be generalized in case of many different variable names).

```r
rowMeansAcc <- function(df, v) {
  m <- as.matrix(df[, grep(v, colnames(df))])
  m_mean <- sapply(1:ncol(m), \(i) rowMeans(m[, 1:i, drop = FALSE]))[, -1, drop = FALSE]
  colnames(m_mean) <- sprintf("%s1_%d", v, 2:ncol(m))
  m_mean  
}

cbind(df, rowMeansAcc(df, "a"), rowMeansAcc(df, "b"))

#>   a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4 a1_2 a1_3 a1_4 b1_2 b1_3 b1_4
#> 1  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100  2.5    4  5.5   25   40   55
#> 2  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110  3.5    5  6.5   35   50   65
#> 3  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120  4.5    6  7.5   45   60   75
```

---

Note: we could slightly modify the wrapper function to be used directly in e.g. a `mutate()` call,

```
library(dplyr) 

rowMeansAcc2 <- function(...) {
  m <- cbind(...)
  m_mean <- sapply(1:ncol(m), \(i) rowMeans(m[, 1:i, drop = FALSE]))[, -1, drop = FALSE]
  colnames(m_mean) <- sprintf("1_%d", 2:ncol(m))
  m_mean  
}

mutate(df, "a" = rowMeansAcc2(a1, a2, a3, a4), "b" = rowMeansAcc2(b1, b2, b3, b4))

#>   a1 a2 a3 a4 b1 b2 b3  b4 a.1_2 a.1_3 a.1_4 b.1_2 b.1_3 b.1_4
#> 1  1  4  7 10 10 40 70 100   2.5   4.0   5.5    25    40    55
#> 2  2  5  8 11 20 50 80 110   3.5   5.0   6.5    35    50    65
#> 3  3  6  9 12 30 60 90 120   4.5   6.0   7.5    45    60    75
```